# SQL copy data from one column to another

Tags: mysql, sql-update

In one table called `xt_products` with several columns.

The ones I am interested are

`products_ean` (varchar 128) and `products_model` (varchar 255)

I would like to copy the values from `products_model` to `products_ean` IF the the entry in `products_model` has more than 10 characters.

e.g. `products_model` has the value of '1-2-3' then not copy
if `products_model` has the value of '12345678910' then copy

Thanks
Andreas

Comment: Please provide the tables structure. [mre]

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev here you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function [`CHAR_LENGTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) in the `WHERE` clause of the `UPDATE` statement to check the number of chars in `products_model`:

```
UPDATE xt_products
SET products_ean = products_model
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(products_model) > 10
```

You may also want to add another condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
AND CHAR_LENGTH(products_model) <= 128
```

because the max length allowed for `products_ean` is `128`.